# MySQL query acting weird

Tags: php, mysql

I've got:

```
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db("db") or die("Error: Cannot select database");
$query = "select password from users where name = '".$_POST['login-userid']."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result == false) {
    echo "Invalid username or password";
} else {
    if (mysql_result($result,0) == hash('sha256', $_POST['login-password'])) {
         echo "Logging in...";
    }
}
```

For some reason I keep getting an error for the `mysql_result` line, even when it shouldn't be executed (when the username doesn't exist, ie $result evaluates to false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) will only return `false` if there is an error. In this case there is no error, there are just 0 rows.

You need to use [mysql_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to get the number of rows returned.

Answer (score 2):

You can `var_dump($result)` and see the value, if it's a resource (according to [php](https://www.php.net/mysql_query)), then your query was successful, if not false is returned. It's a boolean false but your == should still be respected if indeed false was returned.

Comment: I used `var_dump` to check and it is indeed a resource. However, I know for a fact there is no username matching `login-userid` in my database. How is this possible?

Comment: To debug that you need to `var_dump($_POST['login-userid'])` and make sure the value is what you expect. It's odd to me that you would name the $_POST var `login-userid` when you are using it it to query against the `name` column of your database.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query($query);
```

returns the result set of your query. It does not return `true` or `false.`

You may use `mysql_num_rows()` to check if the result of the query exist such as:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query)) {
   // exist
} else {
   // does not exist
}
```