# check username and password

Tags: php, sql

I want check if a username and password exist in my database or not, but my code have problem and I couldn't find it.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT C_ID FROM customer WHERE C_NNAME ='".$_POST['username']."' AND C_PASS = '".$_POST['pass']."'");

if($result=='FALSE'){
    $word .= select_key('keyword', 'K_ID', 'password');
}
else 
{
    $word.= select_key('keyword', 'K_ID', 'Please Complete Feilds');    
}
```

Comment: Please format you question to make it readable, and also please put some indication what is supposed to happen and what actually does happen?

Comment: [Bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) rides again; [don't use `mysql_query`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Stop using mysql_* function and start using PDO or mysqli (you are very vulnerable to sql injection (as Quentin mentions). Also don't you mean $_POST['username'] in stead of $post['username']?

Comment: Don't store passwords in your database without [salting and hashing them](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110360/mysql-query-acting-weird/8110428#8110428

Comment: Why are your passwords saved in cleartext? Use a one way hash to encrypt them

Answer (score 2):

Other than your SQL injections problems, you are using the superglobal array `$_POST` wrong (as you are naming it `$post`).

Try using the correct superglobal variable name - and Google for SQL injections.

Comment: You don't know that for sure, although its likely the case, judging by the question, there _is_ a possibility that such a variable exists, and holds the same data as `$_POST`

Comment: @blockhead You are absolutely right - I'm making this assumption based on the rest of his code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT C_ID FROM customer WHERE C_NNAME ='$name' AND C_PASS = '$password'");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   // There's a match
} else {
   // There's no match
}
```

Also please don't use mysql_ functions use mysqli_ or stores procedures.
The code is not secure against sql injection not a good idea to use this on a public website.

Comment: Using `mysqli` functions over `mysql` functions doesn't guarantee protection against SQL Injection attacks, as you can still write unsafe SQL using `mysqli`. Using prepared statements in the `mysqli` API is one of the means of protection.

Comment: I didn't say anything about the mysqli_ functions been better at preventing sql injection. I said the above code is not safe.
Prepared statements are the way to go to help prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mysql_num_rows` to find out if there was any results.